# 'One person to another' or 'one another'

Tags: phrase-usage

> 1. Our likes are different from one person to another.
> 2. Our likes are different from one another.

Which phrase is suitable, one person to another or
one another?

Comment: Try this [link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/each-other-one-another).

Comment: They're both fine.

Comment: I say that this question lacks context and information. What does the OP want to say?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to say that the two of you do not have the same "likes", then both are wrong, because:

In the first example, "**from one person to another**" refers to differences between **all** people, but you are only talking about **two** people.

In the second example, the phrase "**from one another**" compares two **people** (that's what it means), but you had mentioned **likes** (not people).

So both examples sound non-native.  UNLESS (special case) you are comparing the preferences of everybody in your country which differ from person to person as you go through the entire group... then the first example would be correct.

Instead you could say:  "**We have different likes.**" ... or ... "**You and I have different likes.**"  ... or ... (with voice inflection) "**We like different things, you and I.**"